# A doubt on existence of a linear tranformation with some property

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

Let $U$ and $V$ be the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $U=\{(x,y,z)^T:2x+3y+4z=0 \}$ and $V=\{(x,y,z)^T:x+2y+5z=0 \}.$

Then consider the following statement:

> There exists a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T(U) \cap V \ne \{ 0\}$ and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is not the product of linear polynomials with real coefficients.

**My attempt:**

We can observe that there exits a non-zero vector $v$ contained in the intersection of subspaces $U$ and $V.$
Extend $\{v\}$ to form a basis $\{v,v_1,v_2 \}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3.$  Construct a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $T(v)=v,T(v_1)=T(v_2)=0.$

Now, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $x^2(x-1),$ which is not product of ***distinct*** linear polynomials with real coefficients. (Note: Please see that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is product of linear factors but the factors are not distinct).
This $T$ satisfies all the required conditions of the statement.

The question I had is this:

> Instead of taking a repetition of a linear factor, can I get a linear mapping $T$ such that its characteristic polynomial has an irreducible factor?

The answer is YES. But I am confused as to how it is possible. I am stuck here.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer.
Extend $\{v \}$ to $ \mathcal{B}=\{v,v_1,v_2 \}$ to form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3.$
Now define $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ as $T(v)=v,T(v_1)=v_2$ and $T(v_2)=-v_1.$
Then, with respect to this basis, $T$ has matrix representation,

$$[T]_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So, we have that characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $x(x^2+1).$
Also, $T(U) \cap V \ne \{ 0\}.$

I rest!